# Compressing akka-sbt-plugin output directories to single tar (possibly with sbt-native-packager)?

Tags: sbt, akka, sbt-native-packager

My sbt file uses the `akka-sbt-plugin` to create the Akka microkernel in the `target/<project>-dist` directory. That directory has sub-directories `bin`, `config`, `deploy` and `lib`.

I would like to compress that directory into a single tarball.

I have attempted to use the `sbt-native-packager` with the `Universal` target but I do not understand how to make the `mappings` work.

Is `sbt-native-packager` the way to go? How do I reference the directory created by the `akka-sbt-plugin`? Is there a better way to compress the directory?

*Update - adding more info*

My plugins.sbt, among other things, has:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.6.3")
```

To get the output from `akka-sbt-plugin` I use `dist` in sbt. That yields a directory full of useful things in `target/myproject-dist`. I want to compress that directory into a single tarball (and somehow understand how to link the command onto the output of `akka-sbt-plugin` because I understand that's a best practice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample of build.sbt with sbt-native-packager:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._

packageArchetype.java_application

mappings in Universal ++= {
  ((file("src/main/resources") * "*").get map { f => f -> ("conf/" + f.name) }) ++
  ((file("bin") * "*").get map { f => f -> ("bin/" + f.name) })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do I link the output of akka-sbt-plugin to this?

Comment: Oh, so the akka-sbt-plugin has now been removed. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0-RC1/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html Thanks!